# Avoiding closure by changing intent of a question

Tags: discussion, editing

[How do I find good photography locations for a given location?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/91287/6266)

I came across this generalized question that I would like to see answered, except - it was originally a localized Q. for a particular place only. Then it got edited into its current state, which to me is greatly changing the author's intent.

To compound the issue, the accepted answer for this question is for the former, highly localized version; it also has several comments alluding to problems with the previous text. Post-edit, it only attracted 1 answer with 0 upvotes.

I'm not familiar with this stack, does it allow edits that change author intent? The only meta posts about this indicate no, but are a few years old.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree that this meaningfully detracts from the author's original intent.  It still has mention of the locations of interest, but refocuses on how to identify spots along with encouraging more detail as to why particular locations are good.

That said, I don't know that the generalization was really needed in this case.  It could be answered with good subjective answers even without the edit, as long as they provided the details asked for in the revised version (ie, they supply information supporting why a location is good, rather than a pure unsupported list.)